# Get-PnPListItem : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, pnp-powershell

I am getting the following errors when trying to get list of items from SharePoint online using PnP-PowerShell:

> Get-PnPListItem : The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by
> the server.

> Get-PnPListItem : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host.

This seems to happen when the List of items I am trying to retrieve is large. It might be a timeout error but I am not sure how to fix it. Looking online most people are suggesting updating TLS  `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;` but I am not sure if it will help if it is timeout issue.

Comment: Hi.. I'm getting the same issue so by anychance could you share me how you solved this issue if you did. Thank you

Comment: Hi @ziico. I was trying to get list item of multiple library so I just did 1 Library at a time and whenever I got the error I ran the script again. I didn't find a fix for it unfortunately

Comment: Hi I trying to get only 1 folder from 1 library tho but I'm still getting the error. could please look at my code and see what can I change?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254454/how-to-get-only-specific-folder-item-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Did you check you internet speed? Slower internet speed could hit your computer when Window Auto-Tuning feature is “ON”. You could disable Windows Auto-Tuning level to improve the internet speed if internet speed is slow.

For Reference:
https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/3000